# People who discovered God

Tags: sources-mekorot, tanach

There is a list of people who discovered God on their own somewhere in chazal. Does anyone know where it is? I saw it a long time ago and cannot reacall where.

Comment: @DoubleAA Curious why this is the one marked as duplicate and not the newer post.

Comment: @Scimonster I thought the other was clearer somewhat. Better title, for instance. It's presumably the same user.